# deleted ibdata1 in mysql and I am in a huge trouble :( (LINUX)

Tags: mysql, linux, linode

I know i am dumb, but it's a production database and i am in huge trouble,
I wanted to access the db and i forgot the mysql password, one thing led me to another,
till i deleted the ibdata1 (thanks to chatgpt) and now i am in a pinch, mysql doesn't start and i can't access anything.
I just need to start the database so i can export the data if it's possible.
Please help me.

```
root@localhost:~# systemctl start mysql
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xeu mysql.service" for details.
root@localhost:~# systemctl status mysql.service
× mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2023-06-22 12:07:18 UTC; 14s ago
    Process: 1641 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 1649 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=3)
   Main PID: 1649 (code=exited, status=3)
     Status: "Server startup in progress"
        CPU: 294ms

Jun 22 12:07:18 localhost systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=3/NOTIMPLEM>
Jun 22 12:07:18 localhost systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 22 12:07:18 localhost systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
Jun 22 12:07:18 localhost systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Jun 22 12:07:18 localhost systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Jun 22 12:07:18 localhost systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jun 22 12:07:18 localhost systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 22 12:07:18 localhost systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

```
root@localhost:~# sudo tail -n 50 /var/log/mysql/error.log
2023-06-22T11:45:30.331779Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012981] [InnoDB] Cannot continue operation.
2023-06-22T11:45:30.932065Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.33-0ubuntu0.22.04.2) starting as process 1347
2023-06-22T11:45:30.937894Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2023-06-22T11:45:31.003681Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012592] [InnoDB] Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
2023-06-22T11:45:31.003698Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012593] [InnoDB] The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
2023-06-22T11:45:31.003703Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012594] [InnoDB] If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
2023-06-22T11:45:31.003709Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012646] [InnoDB] File ./ibdata1: 'open' returned OS error 71. Cannot continue operation
2023-06-22T11:45:31.003717Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012981] [InnoDB] Cannot continue operation.
2023-06-22T11:45:31.443411Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.33-0ubuntu0.22.04.2) starting as process 1369
2023-06-22T11:45:31.448765Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2023-06-22T11:45:31.507675Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012592] [InnoDB] Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
2023-06-22T11:45:31.507693Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012593] [InnoDB] The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
2023-06-22T11:45:31.507698Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012594] [InnoDB] If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
2023-06-22T11:45:31.507713Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012646] [InnoDB] File ./ibdata1: 'open' returned OS error 71. Cannot continue operation
2023-06-22T11:45:31.507718Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012981] [InnoDB] Cannot continue operation.
2023-06-22T12:07:15.741932Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.33-0ubuntu0.22.04.2) starting as process 1564
2023-06-22T12:07:15.750132Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2023-06-22T12:07:15.815802Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012592] [InnoDB] Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
2023-06-22T12:07:15.815828Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012593] [InnoDB] The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
2023-06-22T12:07:15.815834Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012594] [InnoDB] If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
2023-06-22T12:07:15.815845Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012646] [InnoDB] File ./ibdata1: 'open' returned OS error 71. Cannot continue operation
2023-06-22T12:07:15.815851Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012981] [InnoDB] Cannot continue operation.
2023-06-22T12:07:16.445381Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.33-0ubuntu0.22.04.2) starting as process 1586
2023-06-22T12:07:16.452038Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2023-06-22T12:07:16.511688Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012592] [InnoDB] Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
2023-06-22T12:07:16.511711Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012593] [InnoDB] The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
2023-06-22T12:07:16.511717Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012594] [InnoDB] If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
2023-06-22T12:07:16.511728Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012646] [InnoDB] File ./ibdata1: 'open' returned OS error 71. Cannot continue operation
2023-06-22T12:07:16.511733Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012981] [InnoDB] Cannot continue operation.
2023-06-22T12:07:16.992627Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.33-0ubuntu0.22.04.2) starting as process 1607
2023-06-22T12:07:16.999282Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2023-06-22T12:07:17.071744Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012592] [InnoDB] Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
2023-06-22T12:07:17.071769Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012593] [InnoDB] The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
2023-06-22T12:07:17.071775Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012594] [InnoDB] If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
2023-06-22T12:07:17.071780Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012646] [InnoDB] File ./ibdata1: 'open' returned OS error 71. Cannot continue operation
2023-06-22T12:07:17.071786Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012981] [InnoDB] Cannot continue operation.
2023-06-22T12:07:17.738538Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.33-0ubuntu0.22.04.2) starting as process 1628
2023-06-22T12:07:17.744771Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2023-06-22T12:07:17.807827Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012592] [InnoDB] Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
2023-06-22T12:07:17.807847Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012593] [InnoDB] The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
2023-06-22T12:07:17.807853Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012594] [InnoDB] If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
2023-06-22T12:07:17.807861Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012646] [InnoDB] File ./ibdata1: 'open' returned OS error 71. Cannot continue operation
2023-06-22T12:07:17.807866Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012981] [InnoDB] Cannot continue operation.
2023-06-22T12:07:18.184843Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.33-0ubuntu0.22.04.2) starting as process 1649
2023-06-22T12:07:18.190614Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2023-06-22T12:07:18.251677Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012592] [InnoDB] Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
2023-06-22T12:07:18.251696Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012593] [InnoDB] The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
2023-06-22T12:07:18.251710Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012594] [InnoDB] If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
2023-06-22T12:07:18.251716Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012646] [InnoDB] File ./ibdata1: 'open' returned OS error 71. Cannot continue operation
2023-06-22T12:07:18.251721Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012981] [InnoDB] Cannot continue operation.
```

Comment: There are numerous questions similar to yours [on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) and [on dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bmysql%5D+deleted+ibdata1). Have you read them?

Comment: The short answer is: you must restore the most recent backup now. If you don't have a backup, then this is a costly lesson about the importance of keeping backups.

Comment: The other lesson is: **don't trust ChatGPT**. It doesn't know anything or find answers for you, it only predicts what words seem to go together to make plausible sentences. It can't tell fact from fiction, so if you use it for things you don't know yourself, then it's the blind leading the blind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well first of all thanks to everyone who gave time for my issue, I was dumb enough to forget ab making a backup but anyways I got my data back.
I sent the .ibd files via sftp into windows where mysql is working well, then created a new database, pulled my project from github, applied the migrations then changed the .ibd files with the ones that I imported. finally I Imported the tablespaces of all the tables one by one using the SQL Alter statement, which got my data back :)
For anyone reading this please backup your databases rn. you really don't wanna feel that pain